# How to Import python based libraries ( Having few classes and functions)in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I have my python module name  message.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
class TestClass1(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def print_args1(self):
        print ("Inside print_args1")
        print (self.arg1, self.arg2)

class TestClass2(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def print_args2(self):
        print ("Inside print_args2")
        #print (arg1, arg2)
        print (self.arg1, self.arg2)
```

How can i import this message in my robot script. And how can i create the objects of these two classes and call their respective instance method within robot framework. My module name (message.py) is not matching with defined class name inside the module.

I can import and use in another python file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import message

obj1 = message.TestClass1(10,20)
obj2 = message.TestClass2(30,40)

obj1.print_args()
obj2.print_args2()
```

Not able import and create objects inside my robot script. In Robot script under setting table

```
*** Settings ***
Library          message.py
```

## How we can create objects of TestClass1 and TestClass2 in robot script. and call their method using those object.

I am able to define python function in python file which is returning me handle of Object. Able to call this Python function in robot and using this object can call their method.

Below is code

```
ef newFun(arg1,arg2):
   return TestClass1(arg1,arg2)
def newFun2(arg1,arg2):
   return TestClass2(arg1,arg2)
=================
 The above two functions    newFun and newFun2 I created in python file and calling these function from robot script. This will return me TestClass1 and TestClass2 handle .
Then we can call their method print_args1 and print_args2 from robot using these objects.


Robot code  is as below.
======================>>>>hello.robot
*** Settings ***
Library          message.py
*** Variables ***
*** Keywords *** 
Create TestClass1 Object
        ${object1} =    newFun    10    20
        [Return]    ${object1}
*** Test Cases ***
First TestCase with TestClass1 object

    LOG    Instantiate TestClass1 Object    console=yes
    ${instance}    Create TestClass1 Object
    LOG    ${instance}
    LOG    Calling print_args1 function using TestClass1 Object    console=yes
    Call Method    ${instance}    print_args1
```

Now instead of creating these objects using python function (in our eg newFun and newFun2) , Is there any way we can create objects directly in robot script dynamically.

Comment: I'm unclear if you're asking for a very basic tutorial on Python import syntax, or if there's something strange going on in Robot Framework that makes normal stuff not work. Can you clarify if `import message` and then using `message.TestClass1(1, 2)` does what you need?

Comment: Hi,  I am able to import this in another python file and It is working. Not able to create these objects in Robot framework. Wanted to achieve this in robot framework

Comment: Are you trying to create keyword libraries, or are your tests specifically wanting to create instances of classes that have more than just keywords?

Comment: Hi Bryan Wanted to create keyword libraires which will return me handle of Object of particular class. I am  updating the thread with more info.